# Is it possible to spoof or reuse VIEWSTATE or detect if it is protected from modification?

Tags: asp.net, security, viewstate, penetration-testing

### Question

ASP and ASP.NET web applications use a value called VIEWSTATE in forms. From what I understand, this is used to persist some kind of state on the client between requests to the web server.

I have never worked with ASP or ASP.NET and need some help with two questions (and some sub-questions):

1) Is it possible to programmatically spoof/construct a VIEWSTATE for a form? Clarification: can a program look at a form and from that construct the contents of the base64-encoded VIEWSTATE value?

1 a) Or can it always just be left out?

1 b) Can an old VIEWSTATE for a particular form be reused in a later invocation of the same form, or would it just be luck if that worked?

2) I gather from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic12 that it is possible to turn on security so that the VIEWSTATE becomes secure from spoofing. Is it possible for a program to detect that a VIEWSTATE is safeguarded in such a way?

2 a) Is there a one-to-one mapping between the occurrence of EVENTVALIDATION values and secure VIEWSTATEs?

*Regarding 1) and 2), if yes, can I have a hint about how I would do that? For 2) I am thinking I could base64-decode the value and search for a string that always is found in unencrypted VIEWSTATEs. "First:"? Something else?*

### Background

I have made a [small tool](http://javahacker.com/sea-surfer-v2/) for detecting and exploiting so called CSRF vulnerabilities. I use it to quickly make proof of concepts of such vulnerabilities that I send to the affected site owners. Quite often I encounter these forms with a VIEWSTATE, and these I don't know if they are secure or not.

**Edit 1:** Clarified question 1 somewhat.

**Edit 2:** Added text in *italics*.

Comment: You refer to ASP as distinct form ASP.NET, are you refering to ASP-Classic?  If so what gives you the impression that it has any concept such as VIEWSTATE?

Comment: Oh, I am just confused. As I stated, I have never worked with any of these technologies and may be way off. So, yes, I am probably referring to ASP-Classic.

Comment: If you are really interested in web app security, you should take a look at the Web Application Hacker's Handbook. It will probably answer a lot of your questions. It has a whole sub section about ViewState. Here is the table of contents: http://mdsec.net/wahh/wahh-toc-2e.pdf Also, you may find this interesting: http://ignatu.co.uk/ViewStateDecoder.aspx A lot of web app pen testing tools like burp suite also have a built in function that will display the view state of a site in a human readable form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to programmatically spoof/construct a VIEWSTATE for a form?

Sure. It's just a Base64 encoded value. Now, since ASP.NET 2.0 there has been an option where the viewstate can be encrypted by the Machine Key, but that is an opt-in feature. Generally, you don't want to be putting anything private in the view state in the first place.

> Or can it always just be left out?

Some of ASP.NET's plumbing requires ViewState, turning it off *completely* is rather difficult if you still want to use the ASP.NET Server Controls.

> Can an old VIEWSTATE for a particular form be reused in a later invocation of the same form, or would it just be luck if that worked?

That's called a [replay attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack)

Yes, it is possible. Here is a [blog post](http://eagle-site.blogspot.com/2010/01/viewstate-replay-attack.html) demonstrating it.

> Is there a one-to-one mapping between the occurrence of EVENTVALIDATION values and secure VIEWSTATEs?

Not really. Event Validation is basically used to ensure that the client side event matches a "possible" event that could have happened on the server. It mostly protects and ensure that hidden inputs like `__EVENTTARGET` haven't been tampered with.